# Can an included jar file, or project, create and manage an SQLite database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to create what is effectively an SDK, which other apps will include in their project. As yet I haven't decided which, but this will either be in the form of a single jar file, or an included library project.

My question is, are either of these includes capable of creating and managing a database, or does the actual main application (the one that is including the project/SDK) have to do that?

Comment: What exactly is the scope of "creating and managing a database"? For example, are you providing some end-user-facing UI? Or are you referring solely with regards to using classes like `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase`?

Comment: No there's no user control or UI elements involved (not concerning the database anyway). I just need the sdk, as you suggest, to use the SQLite classes which persists the data in the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a JAR or an AAR can use `SQLiteDatabase` and related classes, assuming that JAR is compiled against the Android SDK (i.e., not a standard JDK).

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, if the JAR or AAR created a database, and the main project also created a database of the same name, would that cause a conflict?

Comment: @androidneil: Yes, as by default they will use the same directory for the database. I suggest that you name your database something distinctive for your library, such as a name based off of the library's package name (e.g., `com.androidneil.awesomelib_database.db`). Basically, you want something that a user of your library is very unlikely to accidentally choose.